# Segfaults in malloc() and malloc_consolidate()

Tags: c++, debugging, malloc, segmentation-fault

My application segfaults sometimes and mainly in malloc() and malloc_consolidate() when I look at the backtrace in gdb.

I verified that the machine has enough memory available, it didn't even start swapping.
I checked ulimits for data segement and max memory size and both are set to 'unlimited'.
I also ran the application under valgrind and didn't find any memory errors.

Now I'm out of ideas what else might be causing these segfaults. Any Ideas ?

**Update:**
Since I'm not finding anything with valgrind (or ptrcheck), could it be that another application is trashing libc's memory structure or is there a separate structure for each process ?

Comment: Have you had it crash under valgrind?

Comment: No, it didn't crash. Its a realtime application and under valgrind I can only put a very light load on it and it usually only crashes under a heavier load.

Comment: Which operating system is this? Judging by the toolchain, it sounds as if it may be Linux. In this case, no, other applications cannot trash your heap; it's something in your application.

If this only happens under load, that makes it all the more tricky of course... What is different under load? How could this be causing you to trash the heap? Try "torturing" your application as best you can while it's running under Valgrind... how can you best reproduce the conditions that would exist under load? Maybe allocate memory gratuitously, something like that?

Answer (score 34):

From http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html#Heap-Consistency-Checking:

> Another possibility to check for and guard against bugs in the use of
>   malloc, realloc and free is to set the environment variable
>   MALLOC_CHECK_. When MALLOC_CHECK_ is set, a special (less efficient)
>   implementation is used which is designed to be tolerant against simple
>   errors, such as double calls of free with the same argument, or
>   overruns of a single byte (off-by-one bugs). Not all such errors can
>   be protected against, however, and memory leaks can result. If
>   MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 0, any detected heap corruption is silently
>   ignored; if set to 1, a diagnostic is printed on stderr; if set to 2,
>   abort is called immediately. This can be useful because otherwise a
>   crash may happen much later, and the true cause for the problem is
>   then very hard to track down.

Comment: Interestingly my code was crashing on `malloc_consolidate` somewhere deep within the google test library... setting MALLOC_CHECK_ to any value 0, 1, or 2 seems to prevent the crash but no matter what setting I use it doesn't print any additional diagnostic information so I still have no clue what was causing the error.

Comment: Either way I can run my test now so take my upvote lol

Answer (score 19):

Most likely, you're trashing the heap -- i.e., you're writing beyond the limits of a piece of memory you allocated, and this is overwriting the data structures that `malloc()` uses to manage the heap. This causes `malloc()` to access an invalid address, and your application crashes.

Running out of memory would not cause `malloc()` to crash -- it would simply return `NULL`. That might cause your code to crash if you're not checking for `NULL`, but the crash site would not be in `malloc()`.

It's slightly strange that Valgrind is not reporting any errors -- but there are some errors that the default "Memcheck" tool can miss. Try running Valgrid with the ["Ptrcheck" tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/pc-manual.html) instead.

Comment: But shouldn't this have shown up under valgrind ? (Assuming my test coverage was good enough.)

Comment: Your comment seems to have overlapped with my edit -- as suggested there, try running Valgrind with the "Ptrcheck" tool. If malloc() crashes, it's almost certain you're trashing the heap in some way.

Comment: As of Valgrind Release 3.7.0 (5 November 2011), the **exp-ptrcheck** tool has been renamed and scaled down in functionality to _check for overruns for stack and global arrays_ . It is now called **exp-sgcheck** ("Stack and Global Array Checking"). [link](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html)