# segmentation fault while using GDB

Tags: gdb

But when I use GDB errors are

```
 malloc_consolidate (av=0xf46750, bytes=15706800) at malloc.c:4559
4559    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
    in malloc.c
```

The error occur when I am trying to `allocate` memeory for some matrix.

```
allocate(arr(N, M))
```

Then I set breakpoint just at this line. I enter `next`, but the program will not go. Error information appear.

And the error will not always appear.

Comment: Related: [Segfaults in malloc() and malloc_consolidate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100193/segfaults-in-malloc-and-malloc-consolidate). It would help if you could show us a complete stack trace and the relevant parts of the source code.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, Thanks. That post really helps. I am writing out of my allocated memory.